# win32 getting disk physical name / number for an unformated disk

Tags: winapi

I'm trying to retrieve a USB storage disk's 'PhysicalDiskXX' so I can CreateFile it.
Problem is that disk is unformatted and so it is my understanding that I cannot use the get volumes enumerations to cross matches since no volume is created yet.
Basically what I have so far is using SetupDiGetClassDevs to filter devices and SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo to enumerate the devices.
But I can't understand the relationship between the drive number required for PhysicalDiskXX and the device info entry. Device info entry only retrieves the device instance.

Answer (score 0):

How about the [Win32_DiskDrive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394132%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class?

I tried to find the API functions for it, but I couldn't find one.